# My save function works for most aspects of the game, but when I load into the game I have to click on the button for the new saved image to appear?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So it is a clicker game, most areas of my game work and save perfectly fine, however the main click button is set to change from one image to another after a certain level is reached. It works, but I have to click the button in order to make the higher level image appear. How can I fix this?

My save code is setup so that it saves the players level, which makes the higher level image appear when I load, but only after I've clicked the button.

I have triedto save the image directly but kept getting errors, I am using the PlayerPrefs save method and cant work out how to save images ect using PlayerPrefs.

Save code snippet: `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("SavedLevel", LevelSystem.level);`

Game code: `if (LevelSystem.level >= 10) { appleimage.SetActive(false); bananaimage.SetActive(true); }`

Comment: If you put: if (LevelSystem.level >= 10) { appleimage.SetActive(false); bananaimage.SetActive(true); } after the game was loaded in addition to button being clicked, won't that solve your issue? Seems you got code ready, what's exactly the problem? Waiting for save file to be loaded?

Comment: It saves it okay that isnt the issue, Its when you reload the game, it has the higher level image saved however it wont appear until clicked. I want to be able to load in and the higher level image just be there, I dont want to have to click it in order for it to change, hope I explained this clearly, thanks

Comment: Then put if (LevelSystem.level >= 10) { appleimage.SetActive(false); bananaimage.SetActive(true); } after the game was loaded, not in the button click.

Comment: Wishing it was that simple, however the level indicator has the same issue in that (for example) your on level 22, when you reload the game it'll say level 0 but the correct xp, in order for the level to go from 0 to your actual level, it will not appear until the user has gained enough XP to reach level 23, then it will display "Level 23" as normal, but only after the XP has been gained? Very strange bug and its getting on my nerves lol

Comment: Well, I still believe it's that simple :P In my own project I follow just this logic. If I want something refreshed after game load, I refresh it after game load. You did implement changing level when you get enough exp, why don't you implement changing level on game load. For me, it seems you just didn't implement what should be done after game load, yet expect it to do it on its own. If you want that behaviour, maybe you want custom setters, that refresh UI after the game state has changed (don't know if it's a good practice though, to put UI code in setters) or something similar